# Date format for 2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, rfc3339

In my project i am getting **"2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00"** this date format in string i have to convert into NSDate i am using

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]; 

NSDate* dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00"];
```

But when i am print date value using NSLog i am getting value as null.

Please help me out

Thank You

Comment: What language and platform are you using?

Comment: The language is Objective-C, and I guess the user is using Apples own Xcode.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**2020 Update**

---

It turns out that updates to the `NSDateFormatter` make to code from the original answer work as expected, when back in 2010 it would fail to parse

**Objective-C:**

```objectivec
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]; 

NSDate* dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00"];
```

**Swift:**

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: "2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00")
```

**Original answer from 2010**

---

NSDateFormatter won't be able to parse it, because the timezone doesn't conform with [RFC 822 or GMT standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table). The problem is on the last ":" to have it you need the "GMT".

The date that you have respects the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

You will need to use a NSFormatter to parse it. You should use [`getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFormatter/getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:)

Set the string `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
[formatter setLenient:YES];
NSString* buggeredTime = [[sourceDate substringToIndex:26] stringByAppendingString:[sourceDate substringFromIndex:27]];
NSDate* dueDate = [formatter dateFromString:buggeredTime];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"'Time Due: 'hh:mm a  MM/dd/yy"];
NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:dueDate];
[formatter release];
```

(Dunno offhand if the setLenient is needed.)

Comment: Note that the need to do the substring thing has been eliminated in later versions.  You can now specify "ZZZZZ" to accept a timezone in the form "-06:00".

Answer (score 2):

Just use that instead (note the "ZZZ" instead of "Z"):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on a date such as: 2015-02-15T17:21:54.000-06:00

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set a locale for the formatter too. Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2010/qa1480.html)

Answer (score 1):

Google's GData Objective-C Client has a class (GDataDateTime) that can parse RFC 3339 dates.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Elements/GDataDateTime.m

Answer (score 0):

Here is the swift 4 and up implementation.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"
var dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: "2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00")!

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM on January 01, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
//Output: Sat, 1 Jan 2000 12:16:45 +0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
//Output: 2000-01-01T12:16:45+0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Saturday, Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
//Output: 01-01-2000 12:16

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
//Output: Jan 1, 12:16 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
//Output: 12:16:45.000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
//Output: 01/01/2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
//Output: January 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
//Output: 01.01.00

//Output: Customisable AP/PM symbols
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "Pm"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
//Output: Pm

// Usage
var timeFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(timeFromDate)
```