# NSDateFormatter Parse unique format

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am getting over 100 nodes from an XML Feed into my iPhone app.  Among other info I am getting a date.  Here is an example of one of the date feeds: 2012-12-08T00:00:00  How can I parse this data without manipulating the string beforehand?  I've messed with it a little bit, but I just get nil in my dateFromString.  If I can't parse it using NSDateFormatter then I can manipulate the string or of course do whatever you suggest I do.

Here's what I have:

```
NSString *testDate = @"2012-12-15T00:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:testDate];
```

Comment: I actually just found a question exactly like my question.  I flagged this question and it should be closed soon.  Thanks for the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date format for 2008-02-01T10:03:23.793-06:00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615227/date-format-for-2008-02-01t100323-793-0600)

Answer (score 3):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
```

and you do not need your date `alloc`-`init` as it gets overwritten by `dateFromString:`.